# How to create a avro Schema from a python dict

Tags: python, avro

I have a python dict that defines the properties of an avro schema:

```py
schema_dict = {
    'type': 'record',
    'name': 'the_name',
    'fields': [{'name':'id', 'type':'string'}, {'name':'value', 'type':'integer'}]
}
```

How do I create an instance of an `avro.schema.Schema` from this?

The [examples](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.0/gettingstartedpython.html) use `avro.schema.parse` which assumes that the schema is defined as aJSON format string.  I don't have that.  I could go through the rigamarole of writing the dict to JSON and parsing it, but is there a more direct way of constructing the schema from this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`avro.schema.Parse` expects a serialized JSON, but doesn't require that it comes from a file. So you just need to serialise your dict, which you can do using [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

So in your case:

```py
schema_parsed = avro.schema.Parse(json.dumps(schema_dict))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you already have it in a dictionary format there a `make_avsc_object` (which is internally called by `parse` after it does a `json.loads()`).

So you would just do the following:

```py
from avro.schema import make_avsc_object
parsed_schema = make_avsc_object(schema_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
avro.schema.parse(json.dumps(schema_dict))
```

it should work.